# magento export price dont take last date such as history

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

i have a problem but with my magento, it's about export price in export/import profile. i've done it by click run profile in popup but after i check in profile page for export price, the date is not modified for the new one. i checked in history, it listed. (*attachment*). it confuse me when i whan to check the last date for export price. i need to fix it but i haven't got the solution. Really need your help guys..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento default settings are awesome and it always display the latest one first basis in default. Without applying a `filter` the order may not change. It looks like you have filtered it in the basis of either `ID or datewise`.

Please check it again,
The problem is either error in `import/export` or issue in the preference of `Import/Export Profile`. Just create a fresh `Import/Export Profile` and proceed the same process once again and this will be done. Thanks

Comment: i don't get of "create a fresh Import/Export Profile", what must i do with this? is it any script that i must modified or is it any configuration that must i modified? please help..